# Function returns 1 instead of the correct value

Tags: c, function, return

I've a problem with the returned value of a C function.

I've a main function in which I call the function "send" in this way;

```
int go_On;
go_On = send(VOTE_REQUEST, 1);
```

The "send" function is composed as follows:

```
int send(int msg, int flag) {

  // inizialization of some parameters;

  if (msg == VOTE_REQUEST) {

    // Do some operations...

    result = send(VOTE_COMMIT, 1);
  }
  else if (msg == VOTE_COMMIT) {

    // Do some other operations...

    return 10;
  }
}
```

where VOTE_REQUEST and VOTE_COMMIT are constants declared at the beginning of the file.

The problem is that the returned value go_On is 1 instead of 10.
I think that the problem arises by the fact that I call the "send" function inside itself. In fact, if I put

```
return 10;
```

before the line

```
result = send(VOTE_COMMIT, 1);
```

go_On assumes the correct value 10.
Is the call of the "send" function inside itself the source of the problem? How can I solve it so that the returned value becomes 10?

Thanks to everybody who will help me.

Comment: One path of execution doesn't return anything. Turn on your warnings: *warning: control reaches end of non-void function*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the value from the recusive call.
If you send something else than `VOTE_REQUEST` or `VOTE_COMMIT` into the function you should return an error value like `-1`:

```
int send(int msg, int flag) {

  // inizialization of some parameters;

  if (msg == VOTE_REQUEST) {

    // Do some operations...

    return send(VOTE_COMMIT, 1);
  }
  else if (msg == VOTE_COMMIT) {

    // Do some other operations...

    return 10;
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you never have a `return` statement in the first branch of the function. This is *undefined behaviour*.

Maybe you mean this:

```
if (msg == VOTE_REQUEST)
{
    return send(VOTE_COMMIT, 1);
}
else if (msg == VOTE_COMMIT)
{
    return 10;
}

return -1;    // default
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function send(), you are not returning any value when

```
msg == VOTE_REQUEST...
```

try adding a return value...

```
int send(int msg, int param2)
{
    if(msg == VOTE_REQUEST)
        return send(VOTE_COMMIT, 1);
    else if(msg == VOTE_COMMIT)
        return 10;
    else
        return -1;
}
```